# How To Make My Code Less Verbose

Tags: jquery, wordpress, this

I am using jQuery in Wordpress and it is doing exactly what I expect it to do. The problem is that I had to re-write the function I am using 4 times (currently, may be even more later) for the SAME operation. I know that there must be a way to not be so redundant using $(this) but I have not been able to figure out where to use it or how to use it.

this is the code I am using:

```
<script>
var x = jQuery.noConflict();
x(function(){
x(".jab .jabcierre1").hide();
x("h2.c1").click(function(){
    x(".jab .jabcierre1").slideToggle(200);
});



x(".jab .jabcierre2").hide();
 x("h2.c2").click(function(){
    x(".jab .jabcierre2").slideToggle(200);
});

x(".jab .jabcierre3").hide();
 x("h2.c3").click(function(){
    x(".jab .jabcierre3").slideToggle(200);
});

x(".jab .jabcierre4").hide();
 x("h2.c4").click(function(){
    x(".jab .jabcierre4").slideToggle(200);
});


});
</script>
```

But as you can tell the whole purpose of this is to hide a div containg the html I want hidden and to display that div when the h2 title is clicked.
I had to give each h2 a class of 1, 2, 3 and so on so that when the title (h2) was clicked it would not trigger ALL h2s in the page which is why I had to resort to re-writing  the function each time I add a new div.

Ok here is the HTML:

```
<div class="jab clearf">
<h2 class="c1">LAVANDA</h2>
<div class="jabcierre1">
<ul class="benef">
<h3>Beneficios</h3>
<li>Piel Grasa</li>
<li>Relajante</li>
<li>Problemas de Estrias</li>
</ul>

<ul class="ingreds">
<h3>Ingredientes</h3>
<li>Aceite de Palma</li>
<li>Aceite de Coco</li>
<li>Acite de Aguacate</li>
<li>Acite de Pepita de uva</li>
<li>Acite de Almendras</li>
<li>Aceites esenciales</li>
<li>Leche de cabra</li>
</ul>
<img src="http://www.granjaelmolino.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/jabon-artesanal-23.jpg" alt="jabon-artesanal-27" width="350" class="alignright size-full wp-image-455" />
</div>
</div>
<!--  ////////////////////////  termina lavanda      /////////////////////////    -->

<div class="jab clearf">
<h2 class="c2">Romero</h2>
<div class="jabcierre2">
<ul class="benef">
<h3>Beneficios</h3>
<li>Piel Grasa</li>
<li>Ayuda con problemas de Acne</li>
</ul>

<ul class="ingreds">
<h3>Ingredientes</h3>
<li>Aceite de Palma</li>
<li>Aceite de Coco</li>
<li>Acite de Aguacate</li>
<li>Acite de Pepita de uva</li>
<li>Acite de Almendras</li>
<li>Aceites esenciales</li>
<li>Leche de cabra</li>
</ul>
<img src="http://www.granjaelmolino.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/jabon-artesanal-27.jpg" alt="jabon-artesanal-27" width="350" class="alignright size-full wp-image-455" />
</div>
</div>

<!--  ////////////////////////  termina Romero  /////////////////////////    -->

<div class="jab clearf">
<h2 class="c3">Citricos</h2>
<div class="jabcierre3">
<ul class="benef">
<h3>Beneficios</h3>
<li>Ayuda con problema de piel manchada</li>
<li>Ayuda con problemas piel de paño</li>

</ul>

<ul class="ingreds">
<h3>Ingredientes</h3>
<li>Aceite de Palma</li>
<li>Aceite de Coco</li>
<li>Acite de Aguacate</li>
<li>Acite de Pepita de uva</li>
<li>Acite de Almendras</li>
<li>Leche de cabra</li>
<li>Aceites esenciales</li>
</ul>
<img src="http://www.granjaelmolino.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/jabon-artesanal-26.jpg" alt="jabon-artesanal-27" width="350" class="alignright size-full wp-image-455" />
</div>
</div>

<!--  ////////////////////////  termina Citricos  /////////////////////////    -->

<div class="jab clearf">
<h2 class="c4">Almendras</h2>
<div class="jabcierre4">
<ul class="benef">
<h3>Beneficios</h3>
<li>Ayuda con problema de piel reseca</li>
<li>Ayuda con problemas de diabetes</li>

</ul>

<ul class="ingreds">
<h3>Ingredientes</h3>
<li>Aceite de Palma</li>
<li>Aceite de Coco</li>
<li>Acite de Aguacate</li>
<li>Acite de Pepita de uva</li>
<li>Acite de Almendras</li>
<li>Leche de cabra</li>
<li>Aceites esenciales</li>
</ul>
<img src="http://www.granjaelmolino.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/jabon-artesanal-24.jpg" alt="jabon-artesanal-27" width="350" class="alignright size-full wp-image-455" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
jQuery(function($){
    var jab = $('.jab [class^="jabcierre"]').hide();

    $('h2[class^="c"]').on('click', function(){
        jab.filter('.jabcierre' + this.className.slice(-1)).slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow there were 5 answers really fast. Really appreciated them all. But I used the answer of @adeneo because it seemed easiest to implement and the cleanest in terms of code and all I did was copy and paste and that was it! it fully replaced my old code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function into which you pass the selector(s) as a parameter. Then you just use those parameters as variables to know which to hide or show.

```
<script>
  var x = jQuery.noConflict();

  function foo(selector1,selector2){
    x(selector1).hide();
    x(selector2).click(function(){
      x(selector1).slideToggle(200);
    })
  };

  foo(".jab .jabcierre1","h2.c1");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may put the class names in to an array and iterate over this:

```
x(function() {

    var elements = [".jab .jabcierre1", ".jab .jabcierre2"];
    var controls= ["h2.c1", "h2.c2"];

    for ( var n = 0; n < elements.length; n++ )
    {
        x(elements[n]).hide();
        x(controls[n]).click(function(){
             x(elements[n]).slideToggle(200);
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have common class names and even use h2 and use $(this) operator to specify which one to expect. $(this) in your click event handler will give you the object which is clicked. Hope this helps. this should do.

```
<script>
var x = jQuery.noConflict();
x(function(){
x(".jab").hide();
x( "h2" ).on( "click",function() {
  x(this).slideToggle(200);
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a «while» loop?

```
var varCount = 1;
while (varCount < 5){
    x(function(){
        x(".jab .jabcierre"+varCount).hide();
        x("h2.c"+varCount).click(function(){
            x(".jab .jabcierre"+varCount).slideToggle(200);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might want to walk the DOM a bit. Hopefully something similar to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwjcLxnc/) will give you an idea of how to proceed for your specific problem.

The general idea is below where you find the headers you want to make clickable, and then you structure the DOM enough so you can walk it to the div that you wish to control.

```
$('h2').click(function(el) {
  var hideme = $(el.target).next();
  hideme.toggle();
});
```

Comment: I also like this answer because it the code is very compacted and it works. Thanks